# How to use camera positioning like in old versions?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, customization, shortcut

This might be a naive question, however, in the old days of blender, there used to be key bindings for camera adjustments. Those allowed to enter camera view mode and then use the "fly camera" mode.

In the current version of blender (2.79) it is possible to enter camera view <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, then activate fly mode <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, and then use the <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> keys to navigate.

Question is, in camera mode, can the <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> keys be remapped to mouse scroll?

Comment: please be specific, are you using v 2.8 or 2.79?

Comment: @cegaton 2.79. I found the new keys in `CTRL+F` mode are `W,S,A,D`. I'll update question on how to bind the keys.

Comment: you can always enter camera view and then lock the camera to view.